# NodeJS OpenPort module not returning what I'd expect for 2+ ports

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, port

I am using the [NodeJS OpenPort](https://github.com/joeferner/node-openport) module and trying to find two open ports:

```
var op = require('openport');
op.find({
    startingPort: 49152,
    endingPort: 65535,
    count: 2,
    createServer: function(ports, callback) {
        console.log("op_createServer>> " + ports);

    }}, 
    function (err, ports) {
        console.log("op_FoundPorts>> " + ports);
        if(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
            return;
        }
    });
```

What I was expecting is the output would be something like:

```
op_createServer>> 49152 49153
```

Instead it is just

```
op_createServer>> 49152
```

But it's only returning one found port. I know for a fact there is more than one open port in the range 49152 to 65535.

How can I work this `createServer` function to ensure `ports` is an array or somehow extract all the ports wanted from the `count` option?

Alternatively, is there a better node module out there for finding open ports?

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I figured out the answer. You aren't supposed to collect that port data in the `createServer` call. Instead, it goes into the regular callback. See here:

```
op.find({
    startingPort: 49152,
    endingPort: 65535,
    // http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml
    count: 2,
    }, 
    function (err, ports) {
        console.log("op_FoundPorts>> " + ports);
        if(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
            return;
        }
    });
```